# Local Uniform Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence

Suppose $f(x)$ is a positive continuous function on $[0,\infty)$ and that $f(x+u)-f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$ for every given $u\in[0,\infty)$. Prove that, given any $a>0$, $f(x+u)-f(x)\to 0$, as $x\to\infty$ uniformly for $u$ over $[0,a]$.

$f$ is actually called regularly (slowly) varying function. The usual assumption is that $f$ is measurable or a Baire function. I would like to see how the stronger condition on $f$ simplifies the proof of the conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $\varepsilon>0$. For any positive integer $n$ consider the (closed) set $E_n$ of $u\in [0,4a]$ such that $|f(x+u)-f(x)|\leq \varepsilon$ for all $x\geq n$. Then $[0,4a]=\cup_n E_n$, thus there exists $n$ such that $\mu(E_n)>3a$. Then for any $b\in [0,a]$ we have $\mu(E_n\cap [0,3a])>2a$, hence sets $B=E_n\cap [0,3a]$ and $b+B$ must have a common point. Take $c\in B\cap (b+B)$. For $x>n$ we have $|f(x+b)-f(x)|\leq |f(x+c)-f(x)|+|f(x+b)-f(x+c)|\leq 2\varepsilon$ since $c,c-b\in E_n$.

What we actually use here is that $E_n$ are measurable and that inequalities hold pointwise, not a.e. Both problems may be routinely fixed for measirable $f$.

Comment: This proof as you say uses the $E_n$ and equivalently $f$ being measurable with $\mu$ being the measure function. I would rather prefer the proof to use the continuity of $f$ as requested in the question. Also, should it not be $[0,a] = \bigcup_n E_n$ rather then $[0,4a]$? And thus, all subsequent coefficients of $a$ be divided by $4$? By "B and b+B may not be disjoint" do you actually mean "... are not disjoint"?

Comment: @Hans yes, $[0,a]$ should be $[0,4a]$, "may not be disjoint" is "can not be disjoint", i.e. it is impossible that they are disjoint. Continuity allows to work with pontwise inequalities (instead of almost everywhere inequalities), it is itself essential simplification.